# Java - mergeSort using recursion

Tags: java, mergesort

I was going through the below sample program and was trying to understand how the below recursion works, I couldn't understand how the left and the right array elements are sorted, finally merging the two subarrays as below. Any pictorial explanation of the below method would be of great help, as I try to understand the below recursive code.

```
 public static int[] mergeSort(int[] arrayToSort) {

    // BASE CASE: arrays with fewer than 2 elements are sorted
    if (arrayToSort.length < 2) {
        return arrayToSort;
    }

    // STEP 1: divide the array in half
    // we use integer division, so we'll never get a "half index"
    int midIndex = arrayToSort.length / 2;

    int[] left  = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSort, 0, midIndex);
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSort, midIndex, arrayToSort.length);

    // STEP 2: sort each half
    int[] sortedLeft  = mergeSort(left);
    int[] sortedRight = mergeSort(right);

    // STEP 3: merge the sorted halves
    int[] sortedArray = new int[arrayToSort.length];

    int currentLeftIndex  = 0;
    int currentRightIndex = 0;

    for (int currentSortedIndex = 0; currentSortedIndex < arrayToSort.length;
            currentSortedIndex++) {

        // sortedLeft's first element comes next
        // if it's less than sortedRight's first
        // element or if sortedRight is exhausted
        if (currentLeftIndex < sortedLeft.length
                && (currentRightIndex >= sortedRight.length
                || sortedLeft[currentLeftIndex] < sortedRight[currentRightIndex])) {
            sortedArray[currentSortedIndex] = sortedLeft[currentLeftIndex];
            currentLeftIndex++;
        } else {
            sortedArray[currentSortedIndex] = sortedRight[currentRightIndex];
            currentRightIndex++;
        }
    }

    return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sorting is performed in the merging loop:

- if the array is very small (0 or 1 element), `mergeSort()` returns it immediately.
- otherwise, it splits the array into 2 subarrays of approximately the same size, `left` and `right`, which are sorted by calling the same method recursively:

  ```
    // STEP 2: sort each half
    int[] sortedLeft  = mergeSort(left);
    int[] sortedRight = mergeSort(right);
  ```
- the final step iterates over the sorted halves to produce a new sorted array.

The recursive calls complete because they are only performed with sub arrays strictly smaller than the argument array.

Comment: It might be simpler to explain that no actual merging takes place until nested recursive splitting results in two sub-arrays of size 1 element each, at which point those two sub-arrays are merged to create a sorted sub-array with 2 elements. Then the splitting and merging follows the call chain, depth first, left first.

Comment: @chqrlie: Thanks. I could understand what you have explained, as the same was explained in terms of comment in the query. What I don't understand is that the recursive call, how the 2 sub arrays are sorted and how the two sorted subarrays are finally merged using recursion. I did try to understand by an example : arrayToSort has 11 elements, say {4,1,-2, 0, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 3, 8}. left has 5 and right has 6 elements, say - left : {4,1,-2, 0, 4} and right : {6, 7, 2, 5, 3, 8}.. How are these getting sorted individually and merged. Thanks.